# how to add volley image request in an arraylist?

Tags: android, android-volley

I have below code 2 things , `Volley` request that set an image , and `array list adapter` that show static images.

I need help to add the volley request in the array list , **I want the volley images shown in the arraylist**

How to do that can you help me please?

*(note I already have a phpscript for that send me in a json the path url of images)*

The code  :main_activity

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

  final String IMAGE_URL =
            "http://developer.android.com/images/training/system-ui.png";
  mNetworkImageView = (NetworkImageView) findViewById(R.id.networkImageView);

//Instantiate the cache
Cache cache = new DiskBasedCache(getCacheDir(), 1024 * 1024); // 1MB cap

//Set up the network to use HttpURLConnection as the HTTP client.
Network network = new BasicNetwork(new HurlStack());

//Instantiate the RequestQueue with the cache and network.
mRequestQueue = new RequestQueue(cache, network);

//Start the queue
mRequestQueue.start();


ImageLoader mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(mRequestQueue, new LruBitmapCache(
            LruBitmapCache.getCacheSize(mContext)));
mNetworkImageView.setImageUrl(IMAGE_URL, mImageLoader);


CustomListAdapter adapter=new CustomListAdapter(this, itemname, imgid);
list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
list.setAdapter(adapter);

list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String Slecteditem= itemname[+position];
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Slecteditem, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
});

}
```

arraylistadapter

package com.example.p;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private final Activity context;
    private final String[] itemname;
    private final Integer[] imgid;

    public CustomListAdapter(Activity context, String[] itemname, Integer[] imgid) {
        super(context, R.layout.mylist, itemname);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        this.context=context;
        this.itemname=itemname;
        this.imgid=imgid;
    }

    public View getView(int position,View view,ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater=context.getLayoutInflater();
        View rowView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylist, null,true);

        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        TextView extratxt = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        txtTitle.setText(itemname[position]);
        imageView.setImageResource(imgid[position]);
        extratxt.setText("Description "+itemname[position]);
        return rowView;

    };
}
```

and Lrubitmapcache

```
package com.example.p;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.support.v4.util.LruCache;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader.ImageCache;

public class LruBitmapCache extends LruCache<String, Bitmap>
        implements ImageCache {

    public LruBitmapCache(int maxSize) {
        super(maxSize);
    }

    public LruBitmapCache(Context ctx) {
        this(getCacheSize(ctx));
    }

    @Override
    protected int sizeOf(String key, Bitmap value) {
        return value.getRowBytes() * value.getHeight();
    }

    @Override
    public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
        return get(url);
    }

    @Override
    public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
        put(url, bitmap);
    }

    // Returns a cache size equal to approximately three screens worth of images.
    public static int getCacheSize(Context ctx) {
        final DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = ctx.getResources().
                getDisplayMetrics();
        final int screenWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
        final int screenHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
        // 4 bytes per pixel
        final int screenBytes = screenWidth * screenHeight * 4;

        return screenBytes * 3;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in other post you ask me for help.
My image comes from a rest server as Json string Base64 coded. Then I do the next:

```
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ObjectLogados o = items.get(position);
        final ViewHolder holder;
        View vi = convertView;
        if (vi == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.singlerowlog, null);// e' preciso fazer o inflate pois a view nao ainda nao esta em activity alguma
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.ivImgMedLog= (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.ivp_imagemedlog) ;
            holder.tv_usuario = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tv_hnomemedlogado);
            vi.setTag(holder);

        }
        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.tv_usuario.setText(o.getUsuario());
        String imageKey="MED"+String.valueOf(o.getNr_usuario());
        final Bitmap bitmap = Common.getInstance().getBitmapFromMemCache(imageKey);
        if (bitmap != null) {
            holder.ivImgMedLog.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }else {
            holder.ivImgMedLog.setImageDrawable(context.getResources()
                    .getDrawable(R.drawable.empty));
            downloadimage(holder.ivImgMedLog,o.getNr_usuario());
        }

        return vi;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView tv_usuario;
        ImageView ivImgMedLog;

    }

    private void downloadimage(final ImageView imageView,final int nr){
        //final ImageView imageView=imV;
        String url=Common.getServerURL() + "\"RetrieveImageStaff\"";
        JSONArray ja = new JSONArray();
        ja.put(nr);

        JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject();
        try {
            jsonBody.put("_parameters", ja);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        JsonObjectRequest jr = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                jsonBody, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                JSONObject anEntry = null, entries = null;
                String ims = "";
                try {   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    JSONArray LResult = response.getJSONArray("result");
                    String s = LResult.get(0).toString();
                    anEntry = new JSONObject(s);
                    ims = anEntry.getString("imagem");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


                Bitmap decodedByte = null;
                try {
                    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(ims)) {
                        byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(ims, Base64.DEFAULT);
                        decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
                        if (imageView != null) {
                            if (decodedByte != null) {
                                imageView.setImageBitmap(decodedByte);
                                Common.getInstance().addBitmapToMemoryCache("MED"+String.valueOf(nr), decodedByte);
                            } else {
                                imageView.setImageDrawable(imageView.getContext().getResources()
                                        .getDrawable(R.drawable.empty));
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        imageView.setImageDrawable(imageView.getContext().getResources()
                                .getDrawable(R.drawable.empty));
                    }
                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //Log.v(TAG, error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(context, "Erro adquirindo imagem...." + error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        jr.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(Common.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_MS,
                Common.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

        Common.getInstance().addToReqQueue(jr, "jreq"); //reqQueue.add(jr);
    }
```

You can change the request to use volley and  get a image. So, you can change the code as described in https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request.html#request-image to something similar to:

```
ImageView mImageView;
String url = "http://i.imgur.com/7spzG.png";
mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImage);
...

// Retrieves an image specified by the URL, displays it in the UI.
ImageRequest request = new ImageRequest(url,
    new Response.Listener<Bitmap>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Bitmap bitmap) {
            mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }, 0, 0, null,
    new Response.ErrorListener() {
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            mImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_load_error);
        }
    });
// Access the RequestQueue through your singleton class.
MySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(request);
```

Comment: Do you even use some cache? Or some image resizing?
It's a terrible approach to load images directly thought http client without any compression or resizing. In another words - it's a direct road to the OutOfMemoryException.

Comment: My images has a  small size. But if you need, you can add resize or compressing. It´s too easy do it.  And Yes, I use lrucache.

Answer (score 3):

I think for your purpose you should use Picasso or Glide, instead of Volley.

Volley it's a amazing thing, but for list with image loading it's better to use more specific image loading library.

Here are links to Glide and Picasso tools:

- https://github.com/bumptech/glide
- http://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: I have already learned how to use volley is it worth to start over again with picasso ? I already spend time on volley,

Comment: I think you should investigate Glide and Picasso. You will spend maximum a half an hour for each library, but in future you will be able to reduce you developing time for work with image loading.

Comment: @AlexSarapin is correct, among other usages, I used volley for several customized multi-part requests for **uploading** photos to my server, and it's great, but for image loading I use Picasso, it's very robust, modular, and as Alex commented, would probably take you half an hour (including setup), it will also shorten your work time regarding several modifications to the way pictures are presented (e.g. rounded corners, image stretching, etc.)

Comment: @TommySM thanks for your comment, ok then ill start with picasso.

Comment: @AlexSarapin after some investigation you are right , i will start with picasso ( I guess better start now with picasso right ? )

Comment: Picasso is very straightforward and is well documented, I'd start with that, maybe @AlexSarapin will be able to give some insight about Glide.

Comment: Picasso it's a cool library, but I prefer Glide. There are some differents in the caching mechanism between those libraries, and Glide is better for me.
Glide put into chache images with the sizes actual to the Image Views sizes on the device screen. So, for this reason Glide win's in image uploading into Image Views.
Also I have choose Glide because I can customize http client, which will be used for image loading. I think it's correct use one client for all application, and better if this client is OkHttp :)